# Extra Column in Many to Many Relationship in Entity Framework 5.0 reviewed

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using the newest Entity Framework and ran into a problem with Many To Many Relationship when I want to create an extra column.

The issue is the same raised in this older post:
[EF Code First Additional column in join table for ordering purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289160/ef-code-first-additional-column-in-join-table-for-ordering-purposes)

Is it still the problem today that one can not add an extra column without loosing the many to many relation ship (link from object A to B as A.B because the mapping becomes and entity it self) ?

What are the work a rounds ?

1. Look up the a of class A I need and then query for mapping table `where(e=>e.A == a)` to get my Bs? And when I need the extra colums i would do `MappingTable.find(a,b)` ?
2. Are there other modeling options, linq to sql that would make it easier ?

Comment: Can't you add the column to either of the tables? Do you actually need to add to the join table?

Comment: I think i do. Having A and B, A is a set of images, B is a set of questions. Each images can have multiply questions. And in the mapping table i would like to add the correct answer. I don't see how that can be added to either one of the tables. and creating a new table don't make sense as it really is a shared property for the specific relation.

Comment: Isn't that a one to many relation?

Comment: The same question can be used for multiply images. So one question have many images, and a image have multiply quests. I guess thats many to many?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know things haven't changed with EF 5. You would need to do it as the link says to. I like to stick with EF as its easy to use, but that's just my opinion...

Comment: sad panda! is the solution to do a normal many to many then and create one entry with foreign keys to the mapping table. (From a sql view this sounds stupid ) Would it be possible to create a normal many to many and then add the column without entity framework knows about it and model an extra entity mapping to the table without navigation link?

Comment: @s093294 - give it a try and find out.  Please report back with your findings.

Comment: I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666608/how-do-i-assosiate-my-pico-class-with-a-specific-table-in-my-database-with-entit  and the problem is that i dont know how to tell it to use the already existing table and not create it. Getting errors that it cant create it because its already there

Comment: If you make any changes to the db manually, EF either recreates the db or ignores it.

Comment: I didnt make em manually, i just to EF to create the column in its Up() script. Now the Many to Many works and it has the extra column, i just need a way to query for it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  What I did to work-around it was create another derivative DbContext specifically to handle joins. I.E.:

```
public class JoinContext : DbContext
{
    internal JoinContext() : base("name=SampleConnectionString")
    {
        PreventErrorIfDatabaseSchemaChanges();

        // Get the ObjectContext related to this DbContext
        var objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
    }

    public DbSet<StudentImage> StudentImages { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<StudentImage>()
            .ToTable("StudentImages");
            .HasKey(joinTable => new { joinTable.StudentId, joinTable.ImageId });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    private static void PreventErrorIfDatabaseSchemaChanges()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<JoinContext>(null);
    }
}
```

I left the other application context with the Student/Image many-to-many join mapping as-is.  Don't forget to specify a compounded key for the join table (refer to HasKey method above), else EF bombs on databse initialization.

After you have your *special* join context, use a repository to access this context and get or set the desired fields from mapped join table:

```
public class StudentRepository
{
    public int GetImageSortOrder(int studentId, int imageId)
    {
        var joinContext = new JoinContext();

        var joinTuple = joinContext.StudentImages.Find(studentId, imageId);

        return joinTuple.SortOrder;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!