# Code first, customizing the join table

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to create a junction table in a many to many relationship using a similar code shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289160/ef-code-first-additional-column-in-join-table-for-ordering-purposes). It creates my junction table with the additional columns i wanted. My Issue is it creates another table with the keys from the tables in the many to many relationship.

Comment: Please show your code. We're running blind.

Comment: I'm using the very same code show in the link