# One to Many fluent with additional fields

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Let's say I have a manufacturer which produces lots of models. Each model has several attributes, and these attributes should come in a certain sort order. Here is what I did before:

- Table "ManufacturerModel" with

  ```
  public virtual ICollection<VehicleAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
  ```
- Table "VehicleAttribute" with

  ```
  public virtual ICollection<ManufacturerModel> Models { get; set; }
  ```
- and finally ModelBuilder fluent api to connect these two tables so I get a 1:n relationship:

  ```
          modelBuilder.Entity<ManufacturerModel>()
          .HasMany(mm => mm.Attributes)
          .WithMany(a => a.Models)
          .Map(mv =>
          {
              mv.ToTable("Model_VehicleAttribute", SchemaNames.Config);
              mv.MapLeftKey("ManufacturerModel_Id");
              mv.MapRightKey("VehicleAttribute_Id");
          });
  ```

  Works perfect. **BUT**: where do I put the SortOrder column? In my opinion it should be inside mapping table "Model_VehicleAttribute" so I can select a ManufacturerModel and get all Attributes in a sorted order. How can this be achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF Code First Additional column in join table for ordering purposes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289160/ef-code-first-additional-column-in-join-table-for-ordering-purposes)

Comment: Thanks, this is a working solution. But I loose a **lot** of convenience because I can't just say "Model.Attributes.Add(...)" but must first create the Model_Attribute entity, and that for each and every Attribute I like to add to the model. Hmmm... not very satisfying, so I hoped there are other solutions.